# How to remove rows from a data set based on comparison of two dates in R?

Tags: r, date

I have a data set with two variables which both contain a date. One is in the format of YYYYMMDD and the other in YYYY-MM-DD. Want I want to achieve is that - if the date for `date1` is later in time than the date for the same row for `date2`, the row should be deleted, with no action further needed, just delete the rows that match that criterium. In my example, row 2 and 4 should be deleted since `date2` is later in time than `date1`

For example:

```
  date1    date2  
1 20200103 2020-01-09
2 20191202 2019-11-02
3 20200408 2020-04-09
4 20200207 2020-01-04
```

Desired result:

```
  date1    date2  
1 20200103 2020-01-09
3 20200408 2020-04-09
```

Data:

```
date1 <- c('20200103','20191202','20200408','20200207')
date2 <- c('2020-01-09','2019-11-02','2020-04-09','2020-01-04')

df <- data.frame(date1, date2)
```

How should I approach this?

Comment: Assuming that `df$date2` is in `Date` format, You have to convert `df$date1 <- as.Date(df$date1, format = "%Y")` and then you'll be able to compere dat1 > date2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
df %>% 
  dplyr::filter(as.Date(date2, format = "%Y-%m-%d") >= as.Date(date1, format = "%Y%m%d"))
```

Comment: Thanks, such an elegant solution!

Answer (score 3):

Convert both the columns to "date" class and use `filter` to subset.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with('date'), lubridate::ymd)) %>%
  #If you have the older version of dplyr use mutate_at
  #mutate_at(vars(starts_with('date')), lubridate::ymd) %>%
  filter(date1 < date2)

#       date1      date2
#1 2020-01-03 2020-01-09
#2 2020-04-08 2020-04-09
```

Answer (score 1):

A little late but still a worthwhile `base R` solution:

```
pat <- "\\d{4}(\\d{2}).*-(\\d{2})-.*" # define a pattern to match
string <- apply(df, 1, paste0, collapse = " ")  # paste rows to strings
df[!as.numeric(gsub(pat, "\\1" , string)) - as.numeric(gsub(pat, "\\2" , string)) > 0,] # subset df
     date1      date2
1 20200103 2020-01-09
3 20200408 2020-04-09
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, as.IDate)][date1 < date2]
```